# Parse an element of JSON to an obj

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am very new to javscript /Jquery and I have this JSON that I fetch from DB and store on a variable data

```
var data = [{
"content":"Wake Early",
"startDate":"2017-09-06T16:00:00.000Z",
"endDate":"2017-09-07T15:59:59.000Z"},
{"content":"Wake up now",
"startDate":"2017-09-07T16:00:00.000Z",
"endDate":"2017-09-07T17:00:00.000Z"}]
```

and I am using alloyUI scheduler to parse that data but it seems that to make it work, I needed startDate and endDate as an object, is there a way I could do it using `regEx` and locate the " " and delete them or any work around to make the code look like this:

```
[{"content":"Wake Early",
"startDate":2017-09-06T16:00:00.000Z,
"endDate":2017-09-07T15:59:59.000Z},
{"content":"Wake up now",
"startDate":2017-09-07T16:00:00.000Z,
"endDate":2017-09-07T17:00:00.000Z}];
```

Comment: use `JSON.parse(data)`.

Comment: This is confusing, you say you're receiving JSON, which you save to a variable. However, the variable you've shown, is not JSON, it's a JS array.

Comment: There's absolutely no difference between your two code blocks...

Comment: @Salketer Yes there is, the latter is not valid JS or JSON.

Comment: No, RegExp can't create objects, it can be used to manipulate strings. You better find out, what you really have, JSON or array, then fix the question.

Comment: Ah nvm, found it the dates aren't surrounded by "... Well that's not gonna happen lol

Comment: You should check your console. Open it up, paste your 'JSON' in and hit enter and see what happens or use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking, you ask to make startDate and endDate as objects... Ok, what object? I'm guessing a date object. But JSON is not typed, you'll need to use javascript once the json is parsed. But still, you haven't shown us any JSON, just a javascript object hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2017-09-06T16:00:00.000Z` is not a valid value in JS. You need to wrap it in some sort of DateTime Object.

With `var a = Date.parse("2017-09-06T16:00:00.000Z")` you get the time in milliseconds since 01/01/1970. Then `Date(a)` is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Or just wrap it in quotes?

Comment: It's already quoted. Since OP needs the date as an object, string is not the desired object :)